# What would the skull of my creature look like?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, skeletons, bones

My creature has a completely flat nosebridge, forward facing eyes, canine-like teeth, and horns. I'd also like to ask if the reference posted below has enough room for a large brain, as it is just as intelligent as humans. I'm mostly asking because I can't think of a creature with a flat head shape like this.

[image]

Comment: Some problems there. With the jaw hinge that far back, but the mouth only extending 40% of the distance, it would need *very* flappy loose skin on the cheeks, or it will not be able to open the jaw much. Otherwise.. That head will have much the same conformation as a crocodile, just more prominent eyeholes and brow ridges. NO problem with braincase size, the rear of the head will be very wide (due to eyes needing line of sight past the nose)

Comment: there is no room for a large brain in that head.

Comment: Going with John on this. The head has all the restrictions that an ungulate herbivore has on the brain. Lots of jaw and neck muscles to anchor. Or is it mobility-restricted with head motion, and they eat all soft foods? Is the head wedge-shaped and extremely wide? Not impossible, but stretching it (pun intended)

Comment: Are the horns functional or decorative? It can affect skull thickness and issues with concussions for an animal with a large brain.

Comment: As the only question I know *how* to answer, no, the horns are not functional. They are completely decorative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is a goat.**

[image: goat goat goat]

A freaking mountain goat.

I here assert that because your creature is a goat, its name is Goaty Goaty Goat.

Also the skull look like this:[image]

[Image Source](https://www.skeletonsandskullssuperstore.com/product/american-mountain-goat-skull/)

Comment: NO! I disagree! the name should be [Goaty Mc Goatface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaty_McBoatface) ;-)

Comment: @Fred That's SIR Goaty McGoatface.

Comment: Decent match, if we flip the horns.

Comment: @ProjectApex - thanks for skull addition.  That was the actual question.

Comment: Y'know what? Thank you for the skull.